# Perspective distortion (fisheye effect) for checking subject in image is 2D or 3D

Tags: face-recognition

I've read from research papers ([link1](https://www.facetec.com/FaceTec_3D_Face_Matching_Whitepaper.pdf), [link2](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9953623)) and some posts ([link3](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/biometrics-why-advanced-liveness-necessity-when-comes-steve-cook/), [link4](https://www.biometricupdate.com/201811/facetec-embraces-new-iso-based-anti-spoof-testing-for-face-biometrics)) that the fisheye effect (perspective distortion) will be observed as we move camera closer to 3D subject (to be concrete 3D subject here is face). Conversely, no significant perspective distortion occurs when moving the camera closer to 2D.

I'm trying to take advantage of this fact for liveness detection / anti-spoofing app. This should hopefully reduce spoofs that are Presentation Attack Detection (PAD) spoofs (printed faces, face images from displays, etc.)

I don't know how to accomplish this? My thoughts are: if there is a way to measure perspective distortion then using some threshold value for it maybe used to determine if subject is 3D or 2D.

How to achive this?

Comment: The problem is that if you have a video played in front of the camera, the video will also have that distortion in its recording, so you won't be able to check it... instead, you should take 2 pictures from your camera at different distances, then you might be able to do it with some ML (opinion)

Comment: @Alberto thank you for comment, indeed I've observed distortion in video reply attacks. I've managed to utilize distortion effect and it works very good, only issue is as you said video reply attacks. Maybe you have some idea about state-of-the-art methods for detection video replys?